# Injecting additional mvc logic into ext js app

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to ext js, but went through the getting started guide and have managed to create my own app.

Now I'm building a plugin for an e-commerce system (shopware) and need to dynamically extend an app.

I've managed to add a view by monkey patching an existing controller:

```
//{extends file="[default]backend/article/controller/main.js"}
//{namespace name=backend/article/view/main}
//{block name="backend/article/controller/main" append}
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.Article.controller.MyApp', {
    override: 'Shopware.apps.Article.controller.Main',
    openMainWindow: function() {
        var me         = this,
            mainwindow = me.callOverridden();    
            oldTabCreation  = mainwindow.createMainTabPanel;
            mainwindow.createMainTabPanel = function() {
                  mainTab = oldTabCreation.apply(this);
                  mainTab.add(
                      Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel',
                          {
                                title: 'Pricify',
                                layout: 'card'
                          })
                  );
                  return mainTab;
            };
        return mainwindow;
    }
});
//{/block}
```

This works. I'm not sure, if it's the preferred way, but the View gets loaded at the right place and I'm quite happy (as it costs me several hours).

But there's some way to go.

How would I inject the entire logic here?

My requirements are:

- I need a controller, a view and a store/model
- Preferably in an own namespace
- I want to separate my classes into files.
- the file must reside in the plugin folder, not in the original app folder.

I could append code to the app.js file, but as far as I know, I can't attach controllers and views, nor would I know how to autoload the files.

Is there any preferred way of doing so?

**EDIT**
I'm now building a simple app, that's loaded before and try to inject the controllers that are then available into the app. I'll report back, once I'm ready.

Comment: What is monkey patching :)? Are you using the ExtJS MVC architecture? If not [tut here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/the-mvc-application-architecture/)

Comment: Yes, I do use it, but I try to extend it. See [Monkey Patch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

Answer (score 1):

Usually I would do something like this by intercepting controller events (with [Ext.ux.Application](https://github.com/nohuhu/Ext.ux.Application) override) and adding some logic on top of that. Alternatively you could extend existing controller and replace it with your custom one in the whole app, if that's feasible. Otherwise monkey patching could be the only way to extend an existing monolithic application that wasn't written with extensibility in mind.

Also, 4.2 Beta 2 should be available shortly; it includes a whole host of MVC improvements, including something like the override mentioned above. You may want to take a look at it.